# Large title to regular title and back

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to have one view with a large title then push another view with a regular title and then return back to previous with a large title.

I have tried setting `prefersLargeTitles = true` in the first view in `viewWillAppear` and setting `prefersLargeTitles = false` in the second view in `viewWillAppear`. This works, but the title does not have a smooth transition like it normally does when going from the second view to the first view.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let secondViewController = secondViewController.storyboardInstance() {
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
  }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
  }

}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing your code?

Comment: @regina_fallangi updated

Comment: the disappearance of the search bar can be related to you setting the search-bar in `viewWillAppear` every time. Setting it in `viewDidLoad` should solve that part of the problem

Comment: @regina_fallangi I actually just realized that I was hiding the search bar accidentally elsewhere and removing that fixed that part. Just as a note I can keep it in `viewWillAppear` and it works fine. I'm going to update the question to just focus on the title issue

Answer (score 2):

So you are relying on the default value of largeTitleDisplayMode which is `.automatic` and you are using `prefersLargeTitles` to be first `true` then `false`. There's nothing wrong about this, but I do believe that the `.automatic` is a bit confusing because it will take any previous value instead of being set on only the first view controller of a navigation controller.

If you can, I will instead do this:

- `FirstVC` with `largetitleDisplayMode = .always` and `prefersLargeTitle = true`
- `SecondVC` with `largeTitleDisplayMode = .never` and `prefersLargeTitle = true` (yes.. it has to be true..)

The SecondVC has to use `prefersLargeTitle = true` because from Apple documentation we can read this:

> If the prefersLargeTitles property of the navigation bar is false, this property has no effect and the navigation item’s title is always displayed as a small title.

I've write an article that dig a little bit more around this topic where I also explain how to fix `.automatic`
https://www.morningswiftui.com/blog/fix-large-title-animation-on-ios13

Comment: This approach works and animation is NOT choppy. This answer should be selected as the correct one. If someone is interested I have created a [fully working example here](https://github.com/nacho4d/ChangingNavigationLargeTitle/tree/main)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `prefersLargeTitles`property to `false` in the `viewWillDisappear` method of the `FirstViewController`. Something like this should work:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let secondViewController = secondViewController.storyboardInstance() {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works the same as the code I posted above. The issue is that the title still does not smoothly transition when returning to the first view.

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe change the font of the back button in the second view? This led to a strange transition of the title in my case. I could solve this by setting the the font not only for the normal state, but also for the highlighted state.

```swift
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([kCTFontAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey: UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)!], for: .normal)

UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([kCTFontAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey: UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)!], for: .highlighted)
```